# Powershell and HP Standard TCP/IP Printer Port

Tags: powershell, printing, port, wmi

The problem I've run into is that one of our print servers has a bunch of HP printers that are using the "HP Standard TCP/IP Port" rather than a "Standard TCP/IP Port". The problem is, there is no WMI class that interfaces with the HP type tcp/ip port.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Part of me wonders what the difference is between these two ports, and if it would be better to just create new standard ports for all of these HP printers. If anyone has any thoughts on this, i'd like to hear them as well. I don't want to break anything!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2411921) in the MS knowledge base explaining how to convert a HP "Standard" TCP/IP port to a "regular" one. Then you are back to WMI.